# How to detect if user go to a link look like our rule?

Tags: php

example:

I have a webpage abc.com/index.php

I want to detect if user connect to **abc.com/index.php/bbdh**,
**abc.com/index.php/bb/saggfd/gjasgd/hsahgd**, **abc.com/index.php/bb/saggfd/gjas** and so on without having a page like that on my host.

I'm using php and need some way to do that without using .htaccess file.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: you mean you want to create dynamic web pages ?

Comment: @quanganh_developer don't be sarcastic, but without `htaccess` is more likely to be impossible. Can you modify in your host the `Virtual Hosts` file?

Comment: Oh sorry!I did not mean it! I really want to make a framework. I'm finding any way to do that!

Comment: When user access a page that wasn't in my host, the 404 error will show, can I do that any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, every thing you need will be accessible here. E.g. for:

```
abc.com/index.php/bb/saggfd/gjas
```

it would be:

```
/index.php/bb/saggfd/gjas
```

strip the `/index.php` with something like:

```
echo substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
```

and you're set.

---

**Update** on how to handle GET-parameters:

```
// get the full request uri
$requestUri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));

// let php parse that url (though it's just a part of the full url)
$chunks = parse_url($requestUri);

// let php parse the query string
parse_str(isset($chunks['query']) ? $chunks['query'] : '', $chunks['query']);

// debug output
print_r($chunks);
```

Comment: I was going to answer this as :     `<?php
    $path = str_replace("index.php/","",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    echo $path;
    ?>` @Yoshi I must admit sometimes downvoters are trolls. SO should display who downvoted.

Comment: @KarmicDice if it was displayed, an endless revenge-downvote-war would begin. But an option to anonymously contact the downvoter would be nice ;)

Comment: Be you! +1 for your comment. ;)

Comment: Thanks but I'm a newbie, so can you show me more about that,bro?:D
Where can I put it in? I try to put it in index.php but it doesn't work!

Comment: @quanganh_developer `$_SERVER` is a predefined/populated array accessible in PHP. What values you'll get from this array depends, to a degree, on your server. But `'REQUEST_URI'` should always be accessible. So as long as the request goes *through* your `index.php` (like shown in your question) you have all options PHP is giving you to access/use that information.

Comment: Oh you save my life!^^!Thanks you so much! That's very kind of you guys!:D

Comment: How can I get values what are posted by get method throught url in that way?